# Trigonometry - Calculate Earth's radius

Tags: trigonometry

I have been stuck on this trigonmetry problem for hours and I can't solve it. The problem is in another language so I will do my best to translate it.

The problem:
Person A and Person B walks up a mountain. They have been walking for 30 km when they reach the top of a 5 km high mountain. Person A points a straight rod at the horizon and also holds a rope with a weight attached to it. The angle between the rod and the rope is 87.7 degrees. Make a calculation the Earth's radius.

I have tried to simplify the problem by drawing an image of the problem but I'm not getting anywhere. Please help.

Comment: What does person B do?

Comment: Calculate the angle apparently :)

Comment: Hint: [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon#Derivation) may be useful. Falling that, consider a right-angled triangle whose sides are a radius of Earth, a radius plus the mountain's height, and a tangent to Earth, beginning with the rod, that meets the first radius. You'll want an answer close to Earth's empirical radius, of course; that gives you a sanity check.

Comment: Ok I will take a look at that and see if it helps.

Comment: I fail to see the relevance of those $30$ *km*.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I do too.

Comment: If you "take a look" at the right-angled triangle proposed by @J.G. then including an image of it in your Question, or even a word picture with your thoughts, would improve the post.

Comment: @hardmath Why do you put that phrase between quotation marks?

Comment: @Sembfi:  Quoting from your Comment above...